# Hazelcast configuration for distributed data structure

Tags: java, database, distributed, hazelcast

For distributing  data structure i want to configure hazelcast. followed all the instructions mentioned in the documentation but still not able to configure it between two machines connected over networks.
both are reachable but still while running codes its creating separate list on two machines.
I think hazel*.config.xml file is not even being used by the program. because after deleting the config.xml file still program is running.

please help.

Comment: When hazelcast starts, it should log something like: INFO: Using configuration file at /home/hazelcast-2.5/bin/hazelcast.xml..  Is this path correct for your case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the logging. It shows exactly which config file is being loaded. If you config files contains errors or is not found, Hazelcast defaults to a default configuration.

We are thinking about removing this behavior and do a hard failure instead of this silent one because it is confusing.